# Need to understand how cbioDevBytesRW is initialized

Tags: vxworks

I have a VxWorks 5.5.1 project on a MPC862 processor using dosFsLib and getting the bootsec array fails intermittently. In investigating this issue, I get to the call to cbioBytesRW which is in cbioLib.c. So far so good.

My issue is that in cbioLib.c, the function cbioBytesRW calls the cbioDevBytesRW function pointer to perform the read of the the bootsec array and I cannot find where cbioDevBytesRW is initialized.

I have used "ar" and looked into target/lib/ppc/PPC860/common/libos.a but dont see it in the library either.

Can someone help me undertand how cbioBytesRW is initialized, please?

Charles Krinke